# I need to get the current URL, when the pagination changes in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux

```
import { PageLoad} from './PageLoad'
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
  
const Pagination = (props) => {
    const location = useLocation();
    const { currentPage, setPage, totalPages } = props.pageControl;
useEffect(() => {
        PageLoad(location.pathname);
    }, [currentPage]);
}
// function in different js

const PageLoad= (URL) => {
console.log(URL);
}

// parent component
    const [paginationValues, paginationApi] = usePagination();
const { currentPage, totalPages } = paginationValues;
const { setCurrentPage, setTotalPages } = paginationApi;
const pageControl = {
        currentPage,
        setPage: setCurrentPage,
        totalPages,
        tileBuffer: 5
    };
```

I need the current URL of the page when i change pagination, when the component loads i'm getting URL properly. EX:my-lists.html?page=1
when i change the pagination to second page the URL is my-lists.html?page=2 but in console i'm still getting my-lists.html?page=1 even thought my current url is my-lists.html?page=2.

Comment: how do you set the `currentPage` ?

Comment: Are you using anything that handles routing for you? Like `next/router` or `react-router-dom`? A single page app (SPA) does not handle routing like a normal page. Even your current routes are a bit weird with the `.html` extension.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli, Hi, the currentPage is state, i need to get the url when that state changes.

Comment: @AbsoluteZero, yes i'm using react-router-dom. so all i need is get the current url when the state currentPage changes and update it a different state.

Comment: Then why are you using `window.location.href` instead of [this](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation)?

Comment: @AbsoluteZero, Sorry i'm beginner in react. window.location.href won't work?

Comment: @KiranKumarV Could you add the other parts of the code so we can debug it ?

Comment: @Amirhossein, there is just two pages here, if the state changes i need the current URL to console. apparently using the location is not working

Comment: Have you tried useLocation ? (https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-location)

Comment: @Amirhossein can you check my edited code, i have tried useLocation only, if that is correct

Comment: Does this work ?
useEffect(() => {
        PageLoad(location.pathname);
    }, [location]);
}

Comment: @Amirhossein nope its not working, it is giving me the same url

Comment: Hmm seems weird. Could you add the logic that updates the currentPage state ?

Comment: @Amirhossein, i have added the currentPage logic

Comment: What is the library for usePagination ? Or you wrote it by yourself ?

Comment: @Amirhossein, thank you for your help. it is working fine useLocation.